# cv2.cvtColor() from "BGR" to "L*A*B" Without Rounding The Returned Values

Tags: python, opencv, color-space, lab-color-space, cielab

I am trying to get the CIELAB (L*A*B) color values of an `uint8` image as floats values using the `cv2.cvtColor` method.

After I had read the OpenCv [documantation regarding color conversion](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html), that says: "The values are then converted to the destination data type", I tried to cast my image to `float32`. Suspiciously, the converted image (which definitely wasn't monochromatic originally) L*A*B values were only `(100., 0., 0.)`  which corresponds to white `(255, 255, 255)` in BGR.

Here is a my code:

```py
import cv2

random_bgr_image = np.random.randint(0, 256, 2 * 2 * 3).astype(np.uint8).reshape(2, 2, 3)

print(random_bgr_image)
print(cv2.cvtColor(random_bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab))
print(cv2.cvtColor(random_bgr_image.astype(np.float32), cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab))
```

And it printed:

```
random_bgr_image: [[[ 18  56 222]
                    [ 13  69 119]]

                   [[ 60 112 107]
                    [128 191 253]]]
```

```
lab_values_as_uint8: [[[128 190 185]
                       [ 88 145 168]]

                      [[117 117 156]
                       [208 143 168]]]
```

And somehow:

```
lab_values_as_float32: [[[100.   0.   0.]
                         [100.   0.   0.]]

                        [[100.   0.   0.]
                         [100.   0.   0.]]]
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to get the float Lab values of an uint8 image?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The part that you're missing is the fact that images in floating point format expect the intensities to be in range [0.0, 1.0]. You didn't apply the necessary scaling after the cast, so anything that wasn't pure black (as in all zeros) will be considered as white (or beyond white, but it gets clamped). So the output you got is actually correct for the data you fed the algorithm.

Comment: Wow Thanks! It works. Can't believe I missed it.